# Ubuntu gives Connection Refused

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am running a local process with URL configured as hdfs://localhost:9000. HDFS is a Hadoop file system protocal.

```
While I perform a Unix command on Ubuntu 12.0, it gives below error -

Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

My /etc/hosts file has below details -

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ubuntu

/# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

SSH is also in running mode. Not sure how to resolve it. Pleas provide your input.
```

Comment: What does this gives? `jps`
Is hadoop running?

Comment: Yes Hadoop is running. While executing command like -hdfs dfs -copyFomLocal path1 path2 it gives error saying - Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

Comment: Please give output of `jps` or `sudo jps`